# CATransition curling page from top

Tags: objective-c, ios, catransition, page-curl

I realize there is a question with this title but it is not correctly answered.  It seems impossible (on iOS 6 at least) to get a page curl animation to play from the **top** of the screen (i.e. peeling toward the home button).

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
[transition setDelegate:self];
[transition setDuration:parameters.duration];
[transition setType:@"pageCurl"];
[transition setSubtype:kCAAnimationFromTop]; //kCAAnimationFromBottom plays the same thing
[layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"curlAnim"];
```

Note: The answer is *not* "change pageCurl to PageUnCurl" (Uncurl is a different animation).

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my testing, it just doesn't work. I have code using all four directions of every transition type but curl/uncurl from this particular direction doesn't work. It seems to me it's a bug but "pageCurl" transition is not even documented so it's difficult to report it.

Comment: Thanks!  I told my designer and he said it is ok to use a different animation for landscape.  This is the correct answer to the question though.